# EF6 many-to-many table with additional date column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 in **database-first mode** with a table `User`.

I want users to be able to share their profiles with other users by using delegation. For this, I defined a table `UserDelegation` with 2 columns : `IdUser` and `IdDelegatedUser`. Until here, everything is working as expected.

Now, I want to add a column for storing dates in the `UserDelegation` table.
The problem is : I'm not able to call this property in my EF6 entities because the entity `UserDelegation` is not visible. Thus, I don't know where to look for my new property Date

I wonder if there is a way to resolve this problem or if this architecture is wrong ?

Comment: If your many-to-many table contains more than just the foreign keys it should create it as it's own entity and result in navigation properties directly to that table instead of by-passing it.  Have you updated your entities since adding the column to the table?

Comment: Thank you very much DhruvJoshi ! In fact, I had to delete/add my table User to see the new UserDelegationEntity... Now everything is OK. Thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i got based on your description - You can try deleting the entity in the EDMX and try regenerating it.

My Interpretation of what you said:

DbContext

```
    public List<UserProfile> GetProfiles()
    {
        using (var ctx = new UserDatabaseEntities())
        {
            var ret = ctx.UserProfiles.Include("UserDelgations").Select(p => p).ToList();
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

SQL

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserDelgations]
(
    [UserProfileId]                     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  NOT NULL
                                        CONSTRAINT FK_UserProfiles_UserProfileId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.UserProfiles (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,

```
[UserProfileDelgationId]            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  NOT NULL,

[AuditDate]                         DATETIME NOT NULL default(getutcdate()),
```

)
Go

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserDelgations]
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_UserDelgations PRIMARY KEY ([UserProfileId] ASC, [UserProfileDelgationId] ASC)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfiles]
(
    Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        constraint PK_UserProfiles primary key nonclustered (Id)
            constraint DF_UserProfiles_Id default(newid()),

```
UserName NVARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,

CreatedBy          NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL default(SYSTEM_USER),
CreatedDate        DATETIME NOT NULL default(getutcdate()),
```

)
Go